# Uniformly charged disk

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dielectric, conductors

A uniformly charged disk is an isolant or a conductor? Or could it be both of them? I only know its radius and its surface charge density, which is uniform throughout the disk.

Comment: But the disk is already the outside surface, because I know its surface density

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that you meant that the disk has a uniform surface charge across the entire disk, the situation is stable, and there are no externally imposed electric fields. If this is true, then the charges must be held in place, because otherwise the charges at the center of the disk will be redistributed towards the periphery, violating the purported uniform service charge. This means that the disk must be non-conductive.

Comment: The conditions are right. But why have the charges to redistribute in the first place?

Comment: The electrical field will be higher at the center than the edges, because there are more like charges nearby. So, the charges will want to move to lower areas of electrical field, from the center to the edges.